# I am trying to find last inserted record in train_stations table

Tags: mysql, subquery

`SET @v100 :=(select count(*) from train_stations);    select * from train_stations  limit (select @v100)-1,1;`

Error:Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@v100,1' at line 1

this query without user variable also not working
 `select * from train_stations limit (select count() from train_stations)-1,1;`

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select count() from train_stations)-1,1' at line 1

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause doesn't yet support user variables. Have you seen [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?  Do you have an auto_increment column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a user defined variable in `LIMIT`. Rather you can use `PREPARE STATEMENT`. An example below

```
PREPARE STMT FROM 
" SELECT * FROM tab LIMIT ?,1 "; 
select @START := count(*) from tab; 
set @START := @START - 1;
select @START;
EXECUTE STMT USING @START;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
```

A demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ae474/11

**EDIT:**

Essentially you are trying to fetch the last record in your table which you can easily do using `ORDER BY` clause like

```
select * from train_stations order by some_id desc limit 1
```

Comment: PREPARE STMT FROM 
" SELECT * FROM train_stations LIMIT ?,1 "; 
select @START = count(*)-1 from train_stations; 

EXECUTE STMT USING @START;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

query has no errors but showing first record

Comment: @user1495703, would you mind trying again. see edited answer.

Comment: in your example, this query is showing first record; not showing last record

Comment: @user1495703, it will now. get the edited query and Try again.

Comment: Technically probably correct, but why use electro shockers against a mosquito?

Comment: @flaschenpost, sticking to the question been asked by OP.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, I know, but sometimes it helps more to destruct a first wrong step... I could not see a situation where this is better in any sense. As soon as the table gets bigger it will lead to horrible bad performance.

Comment: @flaschenpost, yep that's true but again even if the table is BIG; performance hit won't be much since it's doing a `count(*)`; probably a `count(id)` would be much better. It's just that not following direct route. anyway, Let me include a point.

Comment: @user1495703, don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking the check button below voting button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put an id column or timestamp column in your table? There is no such thing as a "natural order" of rows in MySQL, which you try to rely on.

Then all the magic would collaps to

```
select * from train_stations order by id desc limit 1;
```

or

```
select * from train_stations order by insert_tmstmp desc limit 1;
```

EDIT: The big problem with your approach is that MySQL must go through every row of train_stations just to throw them away and keep only the last one. It is better just to tell MySQL that you want directly this single row.